# Remove items from list where not at *all* locations

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have objects that look something like:

```
public class ListItem {
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    // ... other properties ...
}
```

I have a list of these items (`List<ListItem>`) loaded from the database. These are unique by item id *and* location id. I happen to know there are only 10 total locations (LocationId of 1 - 10).

Is there a LINQ statement I can write to remove items that don't appear at *ALL* 10 locations?

What I have now is something like:

```
myList.RemoveAll(x =>
        // this line would need repeated 10 times to work!
        !myList.Any(y => y.ItemId == x.ItemId && y.LocationId == 1) &&
        !myList.Any(y => y.ItemId == x.ItemId && y.LocationId == 2)
        // etc...
    );
```

Since this only checks one area I have to repeat for all regions - not very elegant code. Any ideas or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use GroupBy to group the elements by `ItemId`, then remove all elements that don't have 10 items in the grouping:-

```
var itemsNotAtAllLocations = myList.GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
                                   .Where(g => g.Count() != 10)
                                   .Select(g => g.Key);

myList.RemoveAll(x => itemsNotAtAllLocations.Contains(x.ItemId));
```

Or if you prefer the query syntax:-

```
var itemsNotAtAllLocations = from item in mylist
                             group item by item.ItemId into g
                             where g.Count() != 10
                             select g.Key;
```

There's a suggestion in the comments to do the following instead:-

```
myList.RemoveAll(x => myList.Count(y => y.ItemId == x.ItemId) != 10);
```

I'd offer the following feedback on that:-

1. I'd be optimising for clarity rather than brevity here. A lot of developers find dense LINQ difficult to read, and a clear statement of intent (`itemsNotAtAllLocations`) can save a lot of time.
2. Your version saves creating a (presumably small) data structure at the expense of iterating over a (presumably large) data structure more often. *Prima facie* that sounds like more work to me, not less.
3. I doubt very much that the performance impact will be significant either way.
4. If performance is important to you, you should set a stakeholder-focused benchmark and measure under realistic conditions.
5. If performance is very important to you, I expect you could do much better by taking a different approach, e.g. can you do the query at the database layer, or can you use a more appropriate data structure (i.e. one that represents the grouping innately) in the first place?

Comment: This is a great idea! Is there a performance ramification for using the same Count idea as follows: `myList.RemoveAll(x => myList.Select(y => y.ItemId == x.ItemId).Count() < 10);`?

Comment: @drew_w, you can probably minify that code to just `myList.RemoveAll(x => myList.Count(y => y.ItemId == x.ItemId) < 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `IList.Contains()` like this:

```
var locationIds = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

myList.RemoveAll(x => !myList.Any(y => y.ItemId == x.ItemId && locationIds.Contains(y.LocationId));
```

Comment: This won't work, this only checks whether each individual record belongs to a valid location id, it doesn't determine whether that record exists in ALL locations.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test1 = from g in myList
    group g by g.ItemId into grp
    select new { key = grp.Key, cnt = grp.Count() };
```

Just check to see if the count is 10 and the key is good.